# Collapsing across all variables in stata

Tags: stata

I am trying to `collapse` all variables in my dataset, which is as follows.

```
date     number_of_patients   health_center      vaccinations
6/25/21  1                    healthcentername   1
6/18/21  2                    healthcentername   2
10/9/20  2                    healthcentername   1
10/2/20  2                    healthcentername   1
10/16/20 1                    healthcentername   1
```

I am trying to `collapse` by date through count into:

```
number_of_patients  healthcentername  vaccinations
8                   healthcentername  6
```

I am trying to do this across all health centers but I can't seem to do it without identifying the specific variables I want to collapse. Unfortunately, this isn't entirely feasible because I have 3500 variables in the dataframe.

Answer (score 4):

Somehow you need to tell Stata which variables you want to sum by health center, but that doesn't mean that you need to type them all. You can use `ds` to create a list of variable names. If you use the option `not` then `ds` will list all but the variable names you are mentioning. Like this:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str8 date byte number_of_patients str16 health_center byte vaccinations
"6/25/21"  1 "healthcentername" 1
"6/18/21"  2 "healthcentername" 2
"10/9/20"  2 "healthcentername" 1
"10/2/20"  2 "healthcentername" 1
"10/16/20" 1 "healthcentername" 1
end

*List all variables but the one mentioned and store list in r(varlist)
ds date health_center, not

*Sum by health center all but the variables explicitly excluded above
collapse (sum) `r(varlist)' , by(health_center)
```